# Copy the Bulk collect data to refcursor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I am using bulk collect and want to copy the data to refcursor so that I can return the data in the procedure. Below is what I was trying

```
 PROCEDURE Pr_Get_Perf_Div_By_Paydate (
                                         p_Cur_Out        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                                     )
       IS
 type ab_rec is record (
       Plan_No number
       , Draft_Invoice_No varchar(20)
    );
 type ab_nt is table of ab_rec;
   l_invoices ab_nt;

BEGIN
SELECT Plan_No,Draft_Invoice_No
        bulk collect into  l_invoices        
  FROM tb_Invoice

Open p_Cur_Out for
   Select * from TABLE (CAST (l_invoices AS ty_pa_output_tbl_t));

END;
```

Select statement is giving error. I m not sure what went wrong there. Please advice?

Comment: "is giving error"?

Comment: Hi Tony,yes this is giving error.

Comment: I'll try again :-) - what error is it giving?

Comment: Hi Tony, this is the error message. 
Error at line 5
ORA-06550: line 112, column 40:
PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06550: line 112, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: What are the datatypes of `tb_Invoice.Plan_No` and `tb_Invoice.Draft_Invoice_No`?

Comment: Plan_No : Number
Invoice_No :  Varchar2(20)

Comment: OK.  Your variable `l_invoices` is of type `ab_nt` but you are casting it to `ty_pa_output_tbl_t`in the select statement.  What is the definition of `ty_pa_output_tbl_t`?  Why isn't `l_invoices` declared as type `ty_pa_output_tbl_t`?

Comment: Ok, tried with this but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Bulk Collect, I used temp Global Table and it worked. I am not sure why I am not able to transfer the data from Bulk Collect to Cursor.